# handle back inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer based on the [example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) in the Android documentation.

When you open the navigation drawer it shows a `MainMenuFragment` inside the drawer. When you select a menu item, it replaces the fragment inside the drawer with a `SubMenuFragment`. This works fine expect for the back button.

Pressing the back button always closes the drawer but I want to use the back button to show the `MainMenuFragment` in the drawer when the `SubMenuFragment` is showing. How can you handle the back button inside the navigation drawer to replace the fragment showing inside the drawer.

Replacing the fragment inside the drawer is not the issue here. I can not figure out how to stop the back button from closing the drawer and have it show the `MainMenuFragment` instead.

My main activity XML (shortened):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ....>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" .../>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/drawer" android:layout_gravity="start" .../>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the relevant parts of my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.drawer, new MainMenuFragment()).commit();

        // setup DrawerLayout and ActionBarDrawerToggle
        ...
    }

    private void showSubMenu() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.drawer, new SubMenuFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've used before in different cases is to add fragments to Fragment BackStack.

So when changing fragment added it to the back stack first.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.drawer, new MainMenuFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And when handling back do the following.

```
int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

if(count > 1)
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Try this and see if it works.

Also check this out : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: Thanks, but how do you handle back? `onBackPressed` of the `Activity` is never called when you press back with the navigation drawer open.

Comment: Set your drawer layout to : 'mDrawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);" onBackPressed() should work , if not try onKeyDown

Comment: Actually, just setting `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` makes the back button work in the drawer without any additional code. However, now the drawer won't close and `onBackPresses()` is still not called.

Comment: oh, wait, `onBackPressed()` is called and it is not working wihout additional code either... There already was a `onBackPressed()` with some code to change the fragment left from earlier experiments.